# Is it possible to create a variable for volumes in docker-compose and share it across services?

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

I am trying to achieve something among these lines but it throws an error `yaml: map merge requires map or sequence of maps as the value` is there a way to achieve something like that?

```
x-backend: &backend
  image: image:1.0
  build:
    context: ./backend
  restart: always

x-backend-volumes: &backend-volumes
    - ./backend/src:${BACKEND_PATH}
    - ./backend/entry.sh:/usr/local/bin/entry.sh
    - ./frontend/src:${FRONTEND_PATH}

services:
  backend_1:
    <<: *backend
    volumes:
        <<: *backend-volumes
        - ./additional_volume:/additional_volume

volumes:
  frontend_dist_1: {}
  frontend_nuxt_1: {}
  frontend_cache_1: {}
  backend_1_files: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YAML merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is exclusively for mappings and cannot be used on sequences. There is no similar feature for sequences. You're out of luck on this one.

Best you can do is to link each item separately:

```yaml
x-backend: &backend
  image: image:1.0
  build:
    context: ./backend
  restart: always

x-backend-volumes:
    - &x1 ./backend/src:${BACKEND_PATH}
    - &x2 ./backend/entry.sh:/usr/local/bin/entry.sh
    - &x3 ./frontend/src:${FRONTEND_PATH}

services:
  backend_1:
    <<: *backend
    volumes:
        - *x1
        - *x2
        - *x3
        - ./additional_volume:/additional_volume
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal by using the `extends` feature in Docker Compose, as detailed in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/). By adding a templates file, I was able to define parent services and extend them with the required, service-specific configurations.

```yaml
extends:
  file: templates.yaml
  service: app
```